# AspxGridView default focused row

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I have an AspxGridView in my project with `AllowFocusedRow="True"`. Every time I load the page (with the table) the first row is focused. When I assign -1 to gvMain.FocusedRowIndex on server side (before the page loading) it doesn't help. But when I change the focused row index on client side:

```
                    Init="function() {
                    gvMain.SetFocusedRowIndex(-1);
```

then it loads the table with first row selected which then disappears. So I guess it is better to define it earlier. But how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution was the PreRender event:

```
protected void ASPxGridView1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if(!IsPostBack)
            ASPxGridView1.FocusedRowIndex = -1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the ASPxGridView's DataBound event as shown below to hide the FocusedRow:

```
protected void ASPxGridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if(!IsPostBack)
            ASPxGridView1.FocusedRowIndex = -1;
    }
```

Comment: wow that's not intuitive.  Would it be possible to do it later in the page lifecycle instead? like LoadComplete?

Comment: It's still the same. And when it gets to the ASPxGridView1_DataBound method ASPxGridView1.FocusedRowIndex is already -1.